# Using Matlab's histogram() to simultaneously plot two sets of data

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have an matrix `A` containing two columns for two sets of data. I want to plot these on the same histogram, using different colors for the bars representing the class intervals. I can do this using `hist(A)`, in which case each column in the matrix is taken as a distinct set of data. I would like to use `histogram()` instead, and also define edges for bins. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simpler than I thought:

```
histogram(A(:,1))
hold on
histogram(A(:,2))
```

This automatically makes the bars transparent, so both can be seen.